# Advanced - If / else if / else -statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to make a minigame where the user has to guess if the his number is higher or lower than the computer's.

I'm having some trouble making the scanner (if it is necessary) and the if / else if / else -statement.

My code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


    public class Main {

        public static void main(String args)
        {
                //This will create the numbers.
            Random userNumber = new Random(10);
            Random comNumber = new Random(10);
            System.out.println("The USER was given the number: " + userNumber);
            System.out.println("The COMPUTER was given the number: " + comNumber);

                //This will ask if the USERS think that their number is HEIGHER, LOWER or EQUAL TO the COMPUTER's number.
            String heigerOrLower = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you thinks that your number is heigher(H), lower(L) or equal-to(e) the computer's? ");

                //This if / else -statement will check if the users choice is right or wrong.
            if(){

            }
        }

    }
```

I don't know how to make the statement check for this:

1) If the user's number is lower than the computer's - and if the user typed in " L " at the same time.

2) If the user's number is equal to the computer's - and if the user typed in " E " at the same time.

3) If the user's number is higher than the computer's - and if the user typed in " H " at the same time.

Comment: Have you written something for us to check?

Comment: What issues are you having? Do you want to know how to take user input? Do you want to know how to put conditions in `if` statement? Do you want to know how to check the two values simultaneously? BTW, Why is `userInput` initialized with `new Random(10)`? You realise that `userInput` in that case is not a number but a `Random` instance don't you?

Comment: Yeah, why is `userNumber` a `Random` number generator anyways?

Comment: Sorry - I've just started to code in Java. I only thought that this was how you made a random number, but if not - how can I then make one? I need a random number because it's what the game is about.

Answer (score 3):

[`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) objects provide a source from which random numbers can be produced -- they are not the random numbers themselves. You only need one `Random` instance:

```
Random rand = new Random()

int userNumber = rand.nextInt(10);
int comNumber = rand.nextInt(10);
```

Now you can compare `userNumber` and `comNumber` numerically. For instance, to accomplish your first point:

```
if (userNumber < comNumber && higherOrLower.equalsIgnoreCase("L")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Good advice, but this doesn't handle the `e` user input. Not that this answer needs too. The question is more than addressed with this answer.

Comment: @crush I've only addressed the OP's *first* question -- the others I leave to him as they shouldn't deviate much from what I've shown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what problem you're having as you haven't even attempted the if statements but you could use multiple ones

You could use multiple if statements.

```
if(condition1) {
    //do stuff
}

if(condition2) {
    //do stuff
}
```

or even an if else block

```
if(condition1) {
    //do stuff
}

else if(condition2) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't compiled, but this should be close enough to give you an idea.

```
if ((userNumber < comNumber) && higherOrLower.equals("L") ) {
   (1)
} else if ((userNumber == comNumber) && higherOrLower.equals("E") ) {
   (2)
} else if ((userNumber > comNumber) && higherOrLower.equals("H") ) {
   (3)
} else {
   ///other
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `Random` is wrong but for case testing you may fund using an `enum` clear and flexible.

```
enum Cmp {

    L {

                @Override
                boolean good(int a, int b) {
                    return a < b;
                }

            },
    E {

                @Override
                boolean good(int a, int b) {
                    return a == b;
                }

            },
    H {

                @Override
                boolean good(int a, int b) {
                    return a > b;
                }

            };

    abstract boolean good(int a, int b);
}

private static void test(int a, int b, Cmp cmp) {
    System.out.println("Cmp="+cmp+" a="+a+" b="+b+" -> "+cmp.good(a, b));
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        test ( 1, 2, Cmp.valueOf("L"));
        test ( 1, 2, Cmp.valueOf("E"));
        test ( 1, 2, Cmp.valueOf("H"));
        test ( 1, 1, Cmp.L);
        test ( 1, 1, Cmp.E);
        test ( 1, 1, Cmp.H);
        test ( 1, 0, Cmp.L);
        test ( 1, 0, Cmp.E);
        test ( 1, 0, Cmp.H);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner bit goes something like this to read a user's input.

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //import java.util.Scanner;
        System.out.println("Enter your choice (H)igher (L)ower (e)ven");
        String userInput = input.nextLine();

        boolean validEntry = false;
        while(!validEntry){
            if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("H")){
                //H was entered and valid
                validEntry = true;
            }else if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("L")){
                //L was entered and valid
                validEntry = true;
            }else if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("e")){
                //e was entered and valid
                validEntry = true;
            }
        }
```

The loop is a valid entry loop and will keep looping until one of the 3 choice is selected. The rest of it checks what the user entered.

The rest of the code is up to you on how to use this if then.